# Congruence Class Subgroups - Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

There is this exercise in my abstract algebra notes:

> Show that the subgroups of  $\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$ are $\{\bar0\}$, $\{\bar0,\bar2\}$ and $\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$

Now I know the criteria for a subgroup

- (i) That the identity element be an element of said subgroup
- (ii) That for any two elements the result of summing them in this case will be an element
- (iii) That an inverse exists for each element

Now I'm asking if there is a way to algebraically prove this instead of checking each subgroup individually, also is it a given that for a congruence class the inverse will be an element, i. e.

$$a \in H \implies a^{-1}\in H$$

Thanks for reading any help is appreciated!

Comment: Well, the only proper non-trivial subgroups must have order $2$ by Lagrange's Theorem. But, any subgroup with $\bar{1}$ will contain all of the elements of the group, as will $\bar{3}$, as they are generators. As such, $\{\bar0,\bar2\}$ is the only proper non-trivial subgroup.

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean by algebraically, but you can note that every subgroup of a cyclic group like $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ is also cyclic, so you can find all subgroups by checking the subgroups generated by each of the divisors of $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it a given that for a congruence class the inverse will be an element, i. e.
>
> ∈⟹−1∈

In general, no. In $\mathbb{Z}$, the inverse of $1$ is $-1$, but $1 \in \overline{1}$ since $4 | (1 - 1)$ and $-1 \in \overline{3}$ since $4 | (-1 - 3)$.

In terms the the congruence classes themselves, the inverse of any congruence class $\overline{a} \in \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is actually another congruence class (which may or may not be the same as $\overline{a}$).

For example, the inverse of $\overline{1}$ is $\overline{3}$ since $\overline{1} + \overline{3} = \overline{1 + 3} = \overline{4} = \overline{0}$, whereas the inverse of $\overline{2}$ is $\overline{2}$ since $\overline{2} + \overline{2} = \overline{2+2} = \overline{4} = \overline{0}$.

Comment: [Here's what I see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjMKE.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Since the group $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ is cyclic, so are all its subgroups. (Why?) Also, use Lagrange's Theorem.